# Can I use $(this) as a javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I'm writing a function which requires knowing the location of the clicked div.

I'm wondering if I can get the location of a clicked object as a javascript variable?

here is the code.

HTML

```
<area shape="rect" coords="103, 0, 213, 25" href="#" onClick="swap3($(this),'product-details','product-specs');">
```

Javascript:

```
function swap3(currentDivId ,oldDivId, newDivId) {
    var oldDiv = currentDivId.nextAll("div." + oldDivId);
    var newDiv = currentDivId.nextAll("div." + newDivId);
    oldDiv.style.display = "none";
    newDiv.style.display = "block";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$()` returns a **DOM element** (like an object that you can work with it's **methods**, **properties**, etc) and if you set a variable to it, the variable must work like an jQuery-Object correctly.  But in my experience, some times that **DO NOT**! and I learn the best way is to get the variable by jQuery-selector (`$`). Your code is correct, but should be better if you apply these changes:

```
function swap3(currentDivId ,oldDivId, newDivId) {
    var oldDiv = $(currentDivId).nextAll("div." + oldDivId);
    var newDiv = $(currentDivId).nextAll("div." + newDivId);
    $(oldDiv).css({"display" : "none"});
    $(newDiv).css({"display" : "block"});
}
```

Comment: Thanks, still not working but I've moved the question here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7368995/why-doesnt-my-div-swap-by-class-work/7369016#7369016 and might have to reword it yet again. 

Cheers!

Comment: Ok. I will look at link, and if I can, I will help you.

Comment: This is not correct. `$(x)` returns a *jQuery object* from the *given DOM element* (the one referred to by `x`, remember that `this` is set to the element raising an event in an traditional event callback).

Comment: By originally purpose of jQuery you are right. But my experience told me some thing else! I know what are you talking about, so thanks.

Comment: `oldDiv` and `newDiv` are already jQuery objects. It is superfluous to pass them again to `jQuery`. `$()` *always* returns a jQuery object and so do most of the methods. What the methods return is mentioned in the documentation. The statement that `$()` returned a DOM element is simply wrong. (-1)

Comment: Read my prev comment please. Regards

Answer (score 3):

`this` refers to the current element.

In jQuery, as they use `$()` to get an element, `$(this)` returns the jQuery equivalent of vanilla JS's `this`.

```
<area shape="rect" coords="103, 0, 213, 25" href="#" onClick="swap3(this,'product-details','product-specs');">
```

Comment: Thanks this answers my question. What would the value of 'this' be in this situation? The id of the <area>?

Comment: If you alert it, it's something like Object[HTMLObject] - a DOM element, containing all the information about the tag, it's children, its attributes, and so on.

Comment: This is not correct. `$(this)` returns a *jQuery object* containing one element -- the current evaluation of `this`.

Comment: What's not right? :s I said `$(this)` returns jQ's equivalent of `this`, then said `this` is an `Object[HTMLObject]`, thus implying `$(this)` is a `jQuery object`. Genuinely interested in what I've got wrong here :)

Comment: If `this` evaluates to a DOM element then `$(this)` doesn't "get" anything -- it only wraps the DOM element. `$(this).jqueryProp` is only "equivalent" to `this.normalDOMProp` in the case where `this` evaluates to a DOM object. Just little details. The comment is more explicit about this than the post.