# Why doesn't my div swap by .class work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors

Having trouble converting the following code from dealing with IDs to Classes.

Basicly what the code does is reveals one Div while hiding another.

In the original version it was simple because the div location was absolute.

With the classes version I need to reveal the next instance of 'product-specs' based on which DIV the onClick was located.

NOTE/EDIT: Their are multiple versions of the same classes on the page. So references to the classes must be specific to the closest instance of the class, based on the location of the link that was clicked.

HTML:

```
<div id="product-details">
    <area shape="rect" onClick="swap3('product-details','product-specs');">
</div>
<div id="product-specs">
    <p>Content</p>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function swap3(oldDivId, newDivId) {
    var oldDiv = document.getElementById(oldDivId);
    var newDiv = document.getElementById(newDivId);
    oldDiv.style.display = "none";
    newDiv.style.display = "block";
}
```

However now I need to add multiple instances of product details Div & Products specs

New HTML:

```
<div class="product-details">
    <area shape="rect" onClick="swap3('product-   details','product-specs');">
</div>

<div class="product-specs">
    <p>Content</p>
</div>


<div class="product-details">
    <area shape="rect" onClick="swap3('product-   details','product-specs');">
</div>
<div class="product-specs">
    <p>Content</p>
</div>
```

New Javascript:

????????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: (I explain the complete code befoe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7368889/can-i-use-this-as-a-javascript-variable), so just put the updated here) remember that when your selector is a className, you will got an array! change the code like this and test again:

```
function swap3(currentDivId ,oldDivId, newDivId) {
    var oldDiv = $(currentDivId).nextAll("div." + oldDivId);
    var newDiv = $(currentDivId).nextAll("div." + newDivId);
    $(oldDiv).each(function(){ $(this).css({"display" : "none"}); });
    $(newDiv).each(function(){ $(this).css({"display" : "block"}); });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In native JavaScript, you'd use `getElementsByClassName()` -- but it's [not supported in IE](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t11) up thru version 8. You can use a purpose-built wrapper script like [this one](http://robertnyman.com/2008/05/27/the-ultimate-getelementsbyclassname-anno-2008/), or use a library like jQuery to abstract away the browser differences.

In jQuery, try something like

```
function swap( oldClassName, newClassName ) {
    $("'." + oldClassName + "'").hide();
    $("'." + newClassName + "'").show();    
}
```

Comment: I'm already using jQuery on the page so that wouldn't be a problem, I've made a few attempts at it using jQuery selectors. As well as trying to use the 'this' reference.

Comment: But if you had multiple instances of product-specs, both would show with that solution. I need a way for the script to know the location the event was triggered from and show only the next instance of .product-specs.

Comment: ah, that's a bit more involved... but if you can guarantee that every 'details' div is immediately followed by its corresponding 'specs' div you can use sibling selectors.

Answer (score 1):

To hide the 'details' div and show the immediately-following div, assumed to be 'specs', try this jQuery snippet. It attaches a click handler to every 'product-details' div, and when it fires, it hides that div and shows its immediate sibling:

```
$(".product-details").click( function() {
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).next().show();
});
```

The reverse behavior (hiding the specs and showing the details) is left as an exercise for the reader ;-)

Comment: How can I specify next instance of 'product-specs'. -- $(this).next(.product-specs).show();  ?

Comment: I think so (tho you need to put the selector argument in the `next()` call in quotes, like `next(".product-specs")`. You only need to pass a selector into next() if you're not sure the very next div is a '.product-specs' div. If each 'details' div is ALWAYS followed by 'specs', no need to pass a selector in to `next()`.

Comment: Actually, no: the docs at http://api.jquery.com/next/ seem to say that the selector is used as a filter for `next()` -- it always finds the very next sibling -- but only returns it if it matches the selector. It does NOT appear to keep looking if the next sibling doesn't match the selector; instead it won't return anything. If you can't guarantee the specs always follow the details, you'd use something like `find()` to keep looking for matching divs. This seems fragile; if the corresponding 'spec' div is several elements away from its details, how do you know you have the correct specs?

Answer (score 0):

Original:

```
function swap3(oldDivId, newDivId) {
    var oldDiv = document.getElementById(oldDivId);
    var newDiv = document.getElementById(newDivId);
    oldDiv.style.display = "none";
   newDiv.style.display = "block";
}
```

jQuery:

```
function swap3(oldDivId, newDivId) {
    var $oldDiv = $('#' + oldDivId);
    var $newDiv = $('#' + newDivId);
    $oldDiv.hide();
    $newDiv.show();
}
```

jQuery Classes:

```
function swap3(oldDivClass, newDivClass) {
    var $oldDiv = $('.' + oldDivClass);
    var $newDiv = $('.' + newDivClass);
    $oldDiv.hide();
    $newDiv.show();
}
```

Comment: I like where you are going with this but it wouldn't work as is because there may be up to 5 instances of 'newDivClass' I need only the next instance of it to be shown and not all the others.

Comment: @PhilipK - add an ID to each product. Even a id="Prod##" so it can be calculated in code. Sounds like you are trying to identify a specific product to show/hide, thats not a good use for classes.

Answer (score 0):

Something else you can do is to wrap each of your products inside a div without any class or id. It does make sense to group them like that, something like

```
<div>    
    <div class="product-details">

        <area shape="rect" onClick="swap3('product-   
details','product-specs');">

    </div>

    <div class="product-specs">

        <p>Content</p>

    </div>

</div>

<div>
    <div class="product-details">

        <area shape="rect" onClick="swap3('product-   
details','product-specs');">

    </div>

    <div class="product-specs">

        <p>Content</p>

    </div>
</div>
```

Note the extra wrapping divs. Now, you can use the parent element to identify the product specs that you have to show. E.g.: (Maybe there's a better way to do it)

```
$('.product-details').click(function() {
    // Find the specs to show
    var $specs = $(this).siblings('.product-specs');
    // Hide the other ones
    $('.product-specs').not($specs).hide();
    // Show the one that you want
    $specs.show();
});
```

Hope it works!